# Single line td with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to truncate some HTML included within a table cell. A link to what I'm trying to do is here http://jsfiddle.net/rBthS/1459/
The HTML for the table is simple...

```
<table>
 <tr><td>
   <p>Something is great</p>
   <p>Something else is great</p>
   <p>And finally everything is great</p></p></td>
 </tr></table>
```

And I'd like to only display the first line of text followed by an ellipsis indicating the overflow, i.e. Something is ...
However because of the paragraphs it appears multiline without any ellipsis.
i.e. 
      Something is ... 
      Something els...
      And finally e...

I need to keep all the HTML formatting i.e. the

tags. 
The CSS I'm using is as follows and works great for text without paragraphs

```
td
{
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: if you add `td p { display: inline; }` it works as expected?

Comment: unless restrained, table cells will expand to their content. By removing your `p` tags, you can display the ellipsis as expected. although, you should set a `word-break` if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set your paragraph tag to inline like so:

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

If I understand correctly, that should work exactly how you explained.